# how to replace an integer array with characters in java

Tags: java, arrays, integer, character

int = 0111254

replace all 0 with 'z'

replace odd integers with 'p'

replace even integers with 'q'

The output should be zpppqpq

My part of the code....

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num;
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    num=sc.nextInt();
    int temp;
    int b[]=new int[10];
    char a[]=new char[10];


    for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++) {
        while(num!=0)
        {
            temp=num%10;

            b[i]=temp;

            num=num/10;
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<b.length;i=i+2)
    {
        if(b[i]==0)
        {
            b[i]=115;
        }

        else if(b[i]%2!=0)
        {
            b[i]=113;
        }
        else if(b[i]%2==0) {
            b[i]=112;
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    {
        a[i]=(char)b[i];
    }

    for(int i:a)
    {
        System.out.print((char)i);
    }
```

it gives a wrong output of q s s s s

Answer (score 2):

You could turn that integer into a string and then use `String.replace()`.

```
String numberString = ""+0111254;
// Replace all 0 chars with z
numberString.replace('0','z');
// etc...
```

Comment: Is it like this ?
As b[ ] is the integer array here

for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++)
  {
   String s=""+b[i];
   s.replace('0', 'z');
  }

Comment: **What about the odd and even integers**
**How do you replace them with characters?**

Answer (score 0):

you can take the numbers into a string and then convert strings into an array, and by using a for loop, take the single number and parse into integer, then apply your logic.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] ary = String.valueOf(sc.next()).split("");

        StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();

        for (String n : ary) {
            int value = Integer.parseInt(n);
            if (value == 0) {
                answer.append("z");
            } else if (value % 2 == 0) {
                answer.append("q");
            } else {
                answer.append("p");
            }
        }

        System.out.print(answer.toString());
    }
```